# PHP pdo mssql external connection via terminal fails

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, terminal, remote-access

- SQL Server 2012 Express on a Windows 7 Professional.
- PHP 5.4
- IIS 7.5

I open a PDO-Connection:

```
$sqlconn = "sqlsvr:server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;database=MyDb";
$pdo = new PDO( $sqlconn, $dbuser, $dbpass );
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

then I execute a Stored Procedure:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare( "EXEC $storedProc ?" );
$query->bindParam( 1, $value );
$query->execute();
$spVals = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

All fine, the connection establishes and I get a record set.

As well with my customer, if he connects from a external client. But if he uses a terminal connection, he doesn't get a record set. The connection is open and the Stored Procedure is found but not executed.
The only different is, the terminal is not member of the same windows domain as the SQL Server.

In Sql Server Configuration Manager, Shared Memory and TCP/IP for Network Configuration are activated.
Sql Server and Sql Server Browser Services are running.

MSSQL is set up for remote connection.

Looks for me as if the $dbuser has not the right to execute Stored Procedures over terminal.

But why?

I don't know, if you get an idea of my problem, so please ask for more information if needed!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a try and catch to see if there is a PDO error. I have a feeling there is something going on with the value that the customer is binding.

`try {
    $pdo = $db->prepare('blah blah');
    $pdo->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}`

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The problem was with the customer. His Communication Interface couldn't read the URL-String if there's a %20 (blank) with it.